# With Vue-cli, when running build, how to organize files in css and js folders after the build?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli-4

By default, Vue-cli creates the files as follows:

```
- dist
-- demo.html
-- style.css
-- file.commom.js
-- file.commom.js.map
-- file.umd.js
-- file.umd.js.map
-- file.umd.min.js
-- file.umd.min.js.map
```

I want the files to be organized this way:

```
- dist
-- demo.html
-- css
--- style.css
-- js
--- file.commom.js
--- file.commom.js.map
--- file.umd.js
--- file.umd.js.map
--- file.umd.min.js
--- file.umd.min.js.map
```

**Bonus question:** Are these common and umd names really necessary? Because in the node_modules folder, I don't see any projects with these names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by modifying your webpack config.

Take a look at this issue here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1967

```
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.module
      .rule('images')
      .use('url-loader')
      .tap(options => Object.assign({}, options, { name: '[name].[ext]' }));
  },
  css: {
    extract: {
      filename: '[name].css',
      chunkFilename: '[name].css',
    },
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    output: {
      filename: '[name].js',
      chunkFilename: '[name].js',
    }
  }
};
```

This is the example given, but you can change the chunkFilname and filename keys to include a folder as part of the path. For instance `'javascript/[name].js'`